# 500 error even request render HTML code

Tags: ajax, tomcat, grails, production-environment

Using ajax to get HTML content from GSP template  .

```
$.get(url,{word:$('#search').val()},fnback)
```

The browser Console raises 500 error .

[image]

However , we get the expected response , but in browser not in callback .
[image]

### Known that this kind of error appears only in production environment .

### This question is related  to [this ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27898228/grails-in-production-env-a-valid-shutdown-command-was-received-via-the-shutdow)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is caused either by Grails or by your application, you will need to determine why; it certainly seems to be happening relatively late in the pipeline since you are getting the correct HTML back (I assume you aren't explicitly rendering a 500 status code in your code by accident).

As for the response you are getting back, it is ignored due to the 500 status. The [$.get](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) function accepts a callback which is only invoked on successful requests. If you put debug lines into your `fnback` function you will see it is never called. If you were to replace the `$.get` with an equivalent [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) call and provide an `error` callback, that function would get the HTML you are seeing returned in the browser's dev tools.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Gregor Petrin answer :

```
$.get(myurl,{word:word},function(d){
   $('div#resp').html(d)

})
```

has been replaced by :

```
$.ajax({url:myurl,data:{word:word}}).always(function(d,status){
   if(status !=='success'){
    d=d.responseText;
   }
    $('div#resp').html(d);
});
```